# Issue with testing a Spring app with JUnit: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException raised only in tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I am running into serious issues trying to run JUnit tests with Spring.

Here is my JUnit class configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml", "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml" })
```

In one of the `applicationContext*.xml` files I do have this:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basenames">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>messagesSecurity</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Please note that my app works fine when I run it from tomcat. It is **only when I run the JUnit tests that I get the following NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 118 more
```

I am quite baffled by this behavior... Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the cause of my problem: I was using a message source **class** instead of using the **interface** which caused proxying issues.

Refactoring my app to use the `MessageSource` interface sorted the problem.

See full conversation [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133009-Issue-with-testing-a-Spring-app-with-JUnit-NoSuchBeanDefinitionException) on Spring forum.